# Update mysql table with select query from another database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two databases and I want to update one table with values from another database table.
I am using the following query but it does not work.

```
UPDATE database1.table1
SET field2 = database2.table1.field2
WHERE database1.table1.field1 = database2.table1.field1
```

I have also tried the following query but it does not work either:

```
UPDATE database1.table1
SET field2 = "SELECT field2 FROM database2.table1"
WHERE database1.table1.field1 = database2.table1.field1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685170/update-mysql-table-with-select-query-from-another-database#comment24012051_16685181), `markup` should be part of the join. Here's the correct one:

```
UPDATE oman.ProductMaster_T
    INNER JOIN main.ProductMaster_T 
        ON main.ProductMaster_T.ProductID = oman.ProductMaster_T.ProductID 
SET oman.ProductMaster_T.Markup = main.ProductMaster_T.Markup
```

you can even add an `ALIAS` to simplify the statement,

```
UPDATE oman.ProductMaster_T o
    INNER JOIN main.ProductMaster_T m 
        ON m.ProductID = o.ProductID 
SET o.Markup = m.Markup
```

Comment: "UPDATE oman.ProductMaster_T.Markup
INNER JOIN main.ProductMaster_T
ON
main.ProductMaster_T.ProductID = oman.ProductMaster_T.ProductID
SET oman.ProductMaster_T.Markup = main.ProductMaster_T.Markup"
PL. ADVISE ME WHERE I AM GOING WRONG

Comment: `oman.ProductMaster_T.Markup` -- what is `Markup`? table name or column name?

Comment: oman is the database, ProductMaster_T is the table and Markup is the column name

Comment: Exactly the reason why I love Stack...had a raunchy query...about to ask a question and found this question with even better formulated question than I could ask and a great answer, thanks @JohnWoo!

Comment: I got Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function with this query.