# Transfering data between one data base to another in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to transfer a couple of columns from an old database to a live database..  The issue I have is that I need the columns to match up with a column on the live database.  For instance let me use an example: My live database has a table like this 
TABLE NAME is ITEMS Then inside the table there would be a columns name ItemLookUp and ExtensionDescription.
So the live table would look something like this:

```
**ItemLookUp**                            **ExtensionDesctiption**              
AAA-06-201                                        'Blank'

BBB-08-201                                        'Blank'

CCC-99-201                                        'Blank'
```

The old database would look like this:

```
**ItemLookUp**                        **ExtensionDescription**

AAA-06-201                                     Toy part

BBB-08-201                                    Mechanic Part

CCC-99-201                                       2x1 Screw
```

So what I am trying to do is make the live database have the information of the old database, but the ExtensionDescription needs to match up with the ItemLookup meaning for example if the ItemLookUp is AAA-06-201 it must have an ExtensionDescription of Toy part...  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a link between the 2 servers? Can perform an update joining the 2 table updating the "ExtensionDescription" where they don't match.

Comment: Yea there is a link between the two servers, I could actually put them on the same server if need be.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try on this. I thik this will help you.
```

> update tbnew
>   set tbnew.ExtensionDesctiption = tbold.ExtensionDesctiption
>   from tbold 
>       where 
>           tbnew.ItemLookUp = tbold.ItemLookUp

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbnew.items a JOIN dbold.items b 
ON a.ItemLookUp=b.ItemLookUp
SET a.ExtensionDescription=b.ExtensionDescription
```

Assuming same server.

Comment: Mihai I am getting an error when trying to run the script you provided "Incorrect syntax near 'a' " I name my databases test and test1 to keep it simple..  Here is what I have                                                                                                                                                                                                    UPDATE test.Item a JOIN test1.Item b
ON a.ItemLookupCode = b.ItemLookupCode
SET a.ExtendedDescription = b.ExtendedDescription

Comment: @user3038531 i think it should put SET in front of JOIN and use From as well, it should look like this: UPDATE test.Item a SET a.ExtendedDescritption=b.ExtendedDescription From  test.Item a JOIN test1.Item b ON a.ItemLookupCode = b.ItemLookupCode.

Comment: @user3038531 Are you sure you have mysql?It should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685170/update-mysql-table-with-select-query-from-another-database

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out.. Thanks for all your help
**update Item 
set ExtendedDescription = X.ExtendedDescription
from Item I
INNER JOIN /*old db name*/raxx.dbo.Item X on I.ItemLookupCode = X.ItemLookupCode
WHERE I.ItemLookupCode = X.ItemLookupCode AND I.ExtendedDescription like ''**